# Visa to attend UK conference from Egypt

Tags: visas, uk, egypt

I'm employed and will attend a conference in the UK but I can't figure out what kind of visa I should be applying for. In the gov.uk website its written I should be applying for a standard visitor visa, but in my application I don't have the option to pick a standard visitor visa.

What appears in my application is type visit and in subtype I have to choose  between business tourism or business academic etc .I work in a university. Should I pick business academic?

Comment: I was told that for conferences, a standard visitor visa is the correct one.

If you are applying via a subcontracted 3rd party, can you ask them where the option for the visitor visa is? Otherwise, select 'academic visit' if it's available.

Comment: They have not updated the website to sync up with the current rules, so a standard visitor visa does not appear in the drop down lists.  As hard as it is to take on board, the drop downs are for rules that don't exist any more.

Comment: I think we have a dupe that I even put a bounty on for this Q, but can't search for it right now.